# NUnit global setup with different namespaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to have a NUnit OneTimeSetUp for the entire assembly?

In my project I have a BaseTest class which is in the namespace `MyProject.Tests.Basics` and I have a setup class which contains the [OneTimeSetUp] method. The SetUp class is in the namespace `MyProject.Tests`

When I run a test that derives from the BaseTest class and is for example in the namespace `MyProject.Tests.Data`, then the OneTimeSetUp method is not called. But when I change the namespace of my SetUp class to the namespace of the test class, then the method is called just fine, but only for this particular test class of course.

So my question is, how can I implement a SetUp Class that works for the entire assembly?

Here are my CodeSamples:

SetUp class:

```
namespace MyProject.Tests
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class SetUp
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

BaseTest:

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.Basics
{
    [TestFixture]
    public abstract class BaseTest
    {
        public BaseTest()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Testclass:

```
namespace MyProject.Tests.Data.IO.Files.DataFiles
{
    public class ExampleTest: BaseTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Example()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, have your `SetUpFixture` class in the global namespace, i.e. don't put it in any namespace.

This is documented in the NUnit docs as below:

> A SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly.

https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setupfixture.html